# How do I get the tr data-id using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

What I want to do is to get the serialized `tr` data for all of the `tr` tags. When I try and alert what I expect to be the id numbers, I get nothing, only a blank alert.

```
<table id="tests" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="498">
      <td>498</td>
      <td>498</td>
    </tr>...
```

And the JQuery:

```
        $("#tests tbody").sortable({
          handle : 'td',
          update : function () {
          var order = $(this).data('id').sortable('serialize');
alert(order);

          }
        });
```

**EDIT:
just to be clear, what I need is to get the serialized array of the items after they have been sorted. I should see a serialized array of the new sort order.**

Comment: have you tried with `parent()`?

Comment: I haven't tried. Would I use `$(this).parent()`?

Comment: Ya, try: `var order = $(this).parent().data('id').sortable('serialize');`

Comment: I just tried it and what I am getting is: `TypeError: $(...).parent(...).data(...) is undefined`

Comment: As Milind suggested - it would help with a JSFiddle. Simply goto http://jsfiddle.net/, enter your CSS, JS, HTML etc... and then save it (be sure to select jQuery as a library.. and also to include the CDN URLs to the plugin you are using too)

Comment: OK, Let me try that. It's long overdue for me to be using it anyway. Thanks for the pointers. I'll be right back

Comment: Wow, that was super easy! http://jsfiddle.net/8Jq3D/

Comment: Yeah, its really easy to use. Not always that simple when doing local debugging/developing, but its a great way to share with others when you need a bit of help. I see you have the issue resolved, so I won't bother spending any more time on it though <G>

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I really appreciate you pushing me to do that with fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
update : function (event,ui) {
  var order = $(ui.item).data('id')
  alert(order);
      }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/714/)**

Comment: Thanks, but its still alerting nothing.

Comment: @NaN:Can you create the fiddle?

Comment: I get this back from your code: `TypeError: $(...).sortable(...).find is not a function`

Comment: You want `data-id` of tr element which is getting dragged right??

Comment: Yes. Also, I did create a Fiddle. Man, that was so easy to use!

Comment: Milind, just to be clear, what I need is to get the serialized array of the items after they have been sorted. I should see a serialized array of the new sort order.

Comment: @NaN:see the answer and fiddle

Comment: Wow, Milind, thank you! I see that it's working now. Will this also give me a serialized array of the new sort order?

Comment: @NaN: Yes you can iterate over table and get them.

Comment: OK, I'm really new to JQuery and I'm not sure how to do that. Can you tell me what I need and I'll see what I can find? I know I need to loop over the results but I'm not sure how exactly. Maybe point me to something I can go off of?